# WPF - WritablebitmapEx render a smooth line

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, writablebitmap

I need to render a "smooth" line using a WritableBitmap' i'm using [WritableBitmapExtenstions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

Every 12 ms i get 12 points consisting of an (X,Y) where the Y is normalized to the center of the screen, and the X represents a pixel on the the image surface (Bitmap) .

Init :

```
 _wb =  new WriteableBitmap((int)mainGrid.ActualWidth, (int)mainGrid.ActualHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
 image.Source = _wb;

 CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
```

CompositionTarget_Rendering :

```
   Point [] points = null;
   if (blocks.TryDequeue(out points)) // blocks is a ConcurrentQueue which gets enqueued on a timer interval on another thread.
   {
       using (_wb.GetBitmapContext())
       {                    
           Draw(points);
       }
   }
```

Draw :

```
   private void Draw(Point[] points)
   {
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;

        if (lastX != 0 && lastY != 0)
        { // Draw connection to last line segment.
            x1 = lastX;
            y1 = lastY;
            x2 = (int)points[0].X;
            y2 = (int)points[0].Y;

            _wb.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, Colors.Red);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < points.Count() - 1; i++)
        {// draw lines. [0],[0] - [1],[1]  ; [1],[1] - [2],[2]   .....and so on.
            x1 = (int)points[i].X;
            y1 = (int)points[i].Y;
            x2 = (int)points[i + 1].X;
            y2 = (int)points[i + 1].Y;

            _wb.DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, Colors.Red);
        }

        lastX = (int)points[points.Count() - 1].X;
        lastY = (int)points[points.Count() - 1].Y;      
   }
```

The result :

[image]

Well the lines are exactly in place , but the way it was drawn was not smooth even tough i used a Writablebitmap and drew all the lines on the Rendering event , each segment was still rendered as a batch.

so to conclude should i draw one pixel at a time in order to make this smooth ? 
if you look as the WritablebitmapEx Curve sample the project named "WriteableBitmapExCurveSample.Wpf" 
(This will require you to download the samples from the link above)

you can see the kind of smoothness i wan't to achieve .

Comment: Why dont you use regular gdi+ like bezier or similar?

Comment: i can try , but i was hoping to use what i know and not go back to winforms

Comment: If you dont find a simpler solution that might help you [DrawCurve](http://floris.briolas.nl/floris/2009/04/addcurve-for-wpf-cardinal-spline/)

Comment: You should not draw lines but a curve of points `int[] pts = new int[] { 10, 5, 20, 40, 30, 30};
writeableBmp.DrawCurve(pts, 0.5,  Colors.Yellow);` as in the example link.

Comment: Could you just add a screenshot of what you are trying to get? Instead of requiring us to download and run a project?

Comment: @klugerama i did , it is the way it was rendered which which is the problem , think of of a line from (0,Height/2) - (Width,Height/2) which would be drawn point by point as if you where drawing it with a pencil , i really don't know what the problem is to understand that i want to render it in a "real time" way , the drawing is not the issue , telling me about curves and anti aliasing no body who commented here understood the problem.

Comment: I forgot about this question , someone just up voted it. any ways the trick is using writablebitmap but only draw when CompostionTarget.Rendering is fired. then the line is rendered smoothly like it is being drawn.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `DrawLineAa` (Aa == Antialiased) extension method instead of `DrawLine`.

Comment: it looks better , but the rendering is exactly the same.
+1 for effort.

Comment: @eranotzap your comment is contradictory. if it looks better then the rendering can't be the same. can you clarify or update your question with the use DrawLinaA?

Comment: what i mean by rendering is the "Smoothness" in which it was drawn right now you get like a flickering addition of segments , where i wan't it to be shown as if i drew it pixel by pixel, like drawing with a pencil , i don't care what i draw it is the way it is rendered onto the screen.( every body here is talking about the smoothness of the line).

Answer (score 2):

For the most proper result, you could apply a post-fx matrix filter. 
http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html

I don't remember well how to implement this with asp.net but i think there is something similar in CompositionTarget.